# How to dynamically store some css, font-style file to react's public folder?

Tags: css, reactjs, electron, styles, font-face

I am working on an epub project using electron with react, and using [epub](https://github.com/julien-c/epub) to parse the epub file. Through this parser, I am able to fetch the `css`, `ttf` those files. However, these files won't be available in a regular way. For example, for current section's html might want to import css like `<link href="flow0003.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, and this `css` file won't be loaded.

To work around this, is it possible to store some files to react's public folder dynamically?

I had been searching online, and it seems impossible to do so due to security reason. I had also searched for similar approach with electron, and it seems there no advices available since this project is using electron with react.

By the way, I am able to dynamically inject style like this:
[Book.tsx](https://github.com/JiahuaZhang/electron-react/blob/master/src/extension/ePub/Book.tsx)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const css = Object.values(book.manifest).filter(({ href }) => href.endsWith('.css'));

    Promise.all(css.map(c => getCss(book, c.id)))
      .then(arr => arr.join('\n'))
      .then(styles => {
        if (!ref.current) return;
        ref.current.setAttribute('style', styles);
      });
  }, [book]);
```

However, the nested improt for font file won't work anyway.

So is it possible for electron with react, to store style sheets, font files to its public folder (and need to be deleted later as well)?

I know that it's possible to parse img, style's data with html. For example, use react's `dom.setAttribute` to dynamically inject style sheet. Similarly, for `img` tag, image's data can be directly injected like `<img src={data:${mimeType};base64, ${imgData.toString('base64')}}>`. So is there any equivalent way for to load font-face?

Answer (score 0):

Use electron's ipcMain and ipcRenderer to communicate, and electron has assets to file system.